# What's the length of the new app-scoped User IDs

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

In Graph API v2.0, Facebook introduced new "App-scoped User IDs". In [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user), the ID field was changed into a string, however the length of the new IDs is uncertain.

Any insights?

Comment: I guess there's no fixed length as with the old `user_id` before. Why is this important?

Comment: I got to set the length of the ID field in my database for optimal performance:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

App scoped user IDs are the same length as other IDs in the Facebook API - a 64 bit number (returned as a string).

In MySQL you could set the column to be a [BIGINT which stores 64 bit integers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html). (or store as a String)

Comment: got source for this? I'm really hoping BIGINT is enough, but nowhere does it say that userids are strictly numeric (or limited to BIGINT)

Comment: We explicitly don't document a format for IDs, they should be treated as opaque strings, in theory they are of arbitrary length. 
Right now user IDs, page IDs and many others are 64 bit numbers, treated as strings, but some IDs (e.g. Post IDs) are longer and aren't ints

Comment: @Igy Good to know. Probably a good idea to store this as a character field of length 40.